# What is the height of the pyramid inside a cube?

Tags: geometry, education, 3d

A Cube labeled $ABCD$(base)-$EFGH$(top) has edge $8$cm. It has a pyramid with base $ABCD$ inside it, with the top-point labeled as $P$. It is also known that the distance from $Q$ (the midpoint of $FG$) to the plane $P-CD$ is $4$cm. What is the height of the pyramid?

---

When I draw the cube and a pyramid inside, I see that the distance from $Q$ to the center of the top square is $4$cm, thus the distance from $Q$ to any plane of the pyramid will be longer than $4$cm.

But the answer key says $3$cm.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the distance from a general plane to a single point? The side PCD of the pyramid defines a plane and the point of this plane at shortest distance to Q does not lie on the pyramid side that is inside the triangle PCD.

Comment: You need to specify the relation of the top vertices and the base vertices. Is it E above A, F above B etc? Or something elseThis may/will affect the relation of the plane containing CD and the midpoint of FG.

Comment: Is this pyramid assumed to be square symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the plane $BCFG$. And, also, assume that the pyramid is regular (square symmetric.)

I am going to use the OP's notations below.

[image]

Centered at $Q$, consider a circle of radius $4$ cm. Determine the two lines (going through $B$ and $C$, respectively) that are tangent to this circle. These lines correspond to the planes $DCP$ and $ABP$.  The common point of these lines corresponds to  the top of the pyramid. The pyramid can be seen as $\triangle BCP$ in the figure above.

The altitude of the pyramid is, indeed, $3$ cm.